# Writing the welcome page in the style of a letter

Tags: style

I am trying to make the [welcome page for the company I work for](http://support.camvine.com) as helpful and friendly as possible. At the moment, I have written the text in the style of a letter, in the sense that I start with "Hi." and end with "Enjoy CODA, The support team."

Are there any contraindications to doing this?

Comment: My only worry in doing something like this would be if you sacrificed navigation to allow space for the welcome message; it doesn't appear that you've done so at all and I think it's a nice personal touch

Comment: Closing as the link is dead and the question isn't detailed enough without the link content to be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually like it! It gives some sort of personal touch to your website while still putting emphasis on what the site is exactly about. It gives me the feeling that there are actual human beings behind this website, which in a support context is a big plus. I think it's better than the classic "welcome" page.

I don't see any objections.